# custom validation error message is not displayed in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Once i clicked the button it has to check the condition. if it is not true, then the custom validation message have to display.

but i don't know it is working or not??

My code is,

aspx.cs

```
 protected void validateendtxt(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
        DateTime startDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(startDateTxt.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ta-IN").DateTimeFormat);
        string str = startDate1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateTime startDate2 = Convert.ToDateTime(str, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ta-IN").DateTimeFormat);
        DateTime endDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(endDateTxt.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ta-IN").DateTimeFormat);
        string str1 = endDate1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateTime endDate2 = Convert.ToDateTime(str1, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ta-IN").DateTimeFormat);


            if (startDate2 >= endDate2)
            {
                e.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.IsValid = true;

            }

}
```

aspx

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID ="cusvalid" runat ="server" ErrorMessage ="It Should be greater" Display ="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="validateendtxt">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Tested your snippet, it works as it should. When `endDateTxt` is not greater then `startDateTxt` it displays the error message.